# How to do an UPDATE with several SELECT in value to update in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update a value which is the result of 2 SELECT

```
UPDATE table2
    SET  value = (SELECT value FROM table1 WHERE table1.id = (SELECT value2 FROM table3 WHERE table3 = Value3 )),
    ValueDate = GETUTCDATE()
    WHERE table2.createdby= USER1
```

I checked that the following  request give me a column of several value :

`select value from table1 where table1.id = (select value2 from table3 where table3 = Value3`

When I tried the update MSSQL retruned me this error message :

```
Msg 512, Niveau 16, État 1, Ligne 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I tried subquery with IN after 'value' is not working

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  We don't know what to do when there are multiple matches.  That is your decision.

Comment: So you need to refine your query to something that will return only one value... what value do you want?

Comment: Don't put `SELECT` subqueries in the `SET` clause. Use `UPDATE target ...SELECT ... FROM target inner join source` if you want to update multiple target rows

Comment: BTW how is `table2` related to table1 and table3? What if `table2.createdby= USER1` returns multiple rows, which of those are going to be updated with which `table1.value` values? If humans can't guess, the database won't be able to do so either

Comment: How many rows do you intend to update? And how many rows match your filter `where createdby =  USER1` (which is not valid tsql but I assume you added the error during posting). Does this table have a trigger that assume a single row was updated?

Comment: @SMor I've to modify 73 lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you cite means that your subquery returns multiple values:

```
   SELECT value FROM table1 WHERE table1.id = (SELECT value2 FROM table3 WHERE table3 = Value3 )
```

This is aproblem because you are comparing the dataset that comes from the above query to a single (scalar) value, and those two things cannot equate.

As mentioned by some comments, a better way to do UPDATEs involving multiple tables is to use a FROM clause like in your SELECT queries directly in the UPDATE:

```
UPDATE table2
    SET 
        table2.value = table1.value,
        ValueDate = GETUTCDATE()
    FROM table2
        JOIN table3 ON table3.value3 = table2.value3 -- (??? condition here is unclear)
        JOIN table1 ON table1.ID = table3.value2
    WHERE table2.createdby= USER1
```

Note that the above, if there are multiple matches for a single row of table2, will use the last value in the recordset for the value.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear *which* subquery is causing this issue.  You can "work-around" the problem by using aggregation or `TOP (1)` and `IN`:

```
UPDATE table2
    SET value = (SELECT TOP (1) value
                 FROM table1
                 WHERE table1.id IN (SELECT value2
                                     FROM table3
                                     WHERE table3 = Value3
                                    )
               ),
        ValueDate = GETUTCDATE()
    WHERE table2.createdby = USER1;
```

However, this is really just a hack (particularly the `SELECT TOP (1))`.  You should understand why there are duplicates and adjust the query accordingly.